# Validating against a duplicate entry in ASP.NET 5 MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Using asp.net 5, MVC 6, code first, entity Framework 7, beta 8.

I understand that some validation can be handled through annotations on properties, e.g. Data Type, min, max values and the jquery scripts, but I'm not sure how in code validation against a duplicate entry getting into the database, like preventing a duplicate e-mail reg on a form.

Is there any annotation that I can use for this on my model property or do I need to code something in my controller to handle this custom validation?   Anyone got an example to share?

Answer (score 0):

EF7 does not have any magic to prevent duplicate values in a table. The only way to validate duplicates is to make a roundtrip to the database. The best way to do this is with a unique constraint. This may be expressed as a unique index. Any attempt to insert a duplicate entry should throw an exception.

That said, you can configure EF7 to recognize the unique index in your database in your OnConfiguring method. See [Indexes : Configuring Your Model](http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modeling/configuring.html#indexes) in the EF7 docs.

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .Index(b => b.Email)
            .Unique();
```

Comment: for EF7:
builder.Entity<User>()
            .HasIndex(b => b.Email)
            .IsUnique(true)